# Dynamically sort array in foreach loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to sort an array as the values are added to it so the divs are sorted when I send them to a mustache template.

Here is my variable:

```
var content = {
    "statuses" : []
}

stamp = new Date(created_at).toUTCString(); // EXAMPLE - Mon, 14 Nov 2016 11:49:54 GMT
```

and the object being created:

```
var status = {
    "source": source,
    "username": user,
    "timestamp": date + " " + time,
    "stamp": stamp,
    "posted": setRelativeTime(date),
    "text": setLinks(text),
    "image": image,
    "embed": embed
}
```

and the sort function currently:

```
content.statuses.sort(function(a,b){
    if(a.stamp > b.stamp){ return 1 }
    if(a.stamp < b.stamp){ return -1 }
    return 0;
});
```

but the grids still aren't sorted chronologically.

Comment: That is because Mon, Tues, and so on does not sort chronologically. Instead save stamp as `new Date(created_at).getTime()`

Comment: @mplungjan answer is correct. Also you can try `content.statuses.sort(function(a,b){
    if(a.stamp.toLocaleString() > b.stamp.toLocaleString() ){ return 1 }
    if(a.stamp.toLocaleString()  < b.stamp.toLocaleString() ){ return -1 }
    return 0;
});`. But Both the results are Same.